# Why include `pg_temp` in `search_path` at all when using SECURITY DEFINER

Tags: postgresql

[The docs recommend setting pg_temp as the last entry in search_path.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY)

Why not leave it out of the list altogether? Would this accomplish the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is right in the documentation you reference:

> Particularly important in this regard is the temporary-table schema, which is searched first by default, and is normally writable by anyone.

So if you don't put `pg_temp` on the `search_path` explicitly, **it gets implicitly put first** on the path. Than means that any temporary table (or view) that a user created manually before calling the `SECURITY DEFINER` function will be taken if the function uses that table name **without an explicit schema qualification**. So you could make the function read or write your table instead of the one it meant to use.

It is clear why that is a security problem, right?